# How should I modify interceptor so that it retry the same request in the background

Tags: angular

I have written an interceptor to refresh the token though it is working fine but I have to  refresh the page to get the data with refreshed token. How should I modify it so that, it just happen in the background?

below is the code snippet:

```
intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log(req);

    let token;
    if (
      this.storageService.getData('authenticationPayload') &&
      this.storageService.getData('authenticationPayload').signInUserSession
    ) {
      token = this.storageService.getData('authenticationPayload')
        .signInUserSession
        ? this.storageService.getData('authenticationPayload').signInUserSession
            .idToken.jwtToken
        : 'token is missing';
    } else {
      token = this.storageService.getData('refreshedToken');
      console.log('refreshToken');
    }
    req = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', token)
    });
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        console.log(err);
        if (
          (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) &&
          !this.storageService.getData('authenticationPayload')
        ) {
          this.dialog.openDialog(
            'Your session has expired. Please logout and login again'
          );
        } else {
          this.dialog.openDialog(
            'Your session has expired. Please refresh the page to reinitiate the session'
          );
          this.auth.refreshToken().subscribe(
            data => {
              this.storageService.clearKey('authenticationPayload');
              this.storageService.setData(
                'refreshedToken',
                data.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
              );
            },
            error => {
              console.log(error);
            }
          );
        }

        return Observable.throw(err);
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: why don't u you just run setInterval which will refresh your token in fixed interval ?

Comment: because I want it to happen in background. using set interval then refresh will refresh the whole page.

Comment: How about this `setInterval(()=>{ makeHttpCall() }, 1000)`. It will not refresh your page

Comment: after making http call, how to return the data to the respective component so that it update it?

Comment: You can use `Observer` and `Subscription` for that.